# Numbered citations in Tufte-Latex 3.5

Tags: bibliographies, citing, incompatibility, tufte

Tufte-LaTeX 3.5 (compiling with PDFTexify)

I need to have my citations in the numbered format e.g. [1], [2], etc.

I tried adding the following to the preamble

`\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` but get an error as long as `[numbers]` is present

Please advise

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). A tip: If you put inline code between backticks '`', it will be highlighted a such: take a peek [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using `tufte-handout` class quit often.
With `biblatex` there's no problem using numbered citations by choosing any of the numbered citation styles offered or designing one for yourself.
For example, my preamble line is:
`\usepackage[style=nature,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

And it works just fine.